# XSS exception being thrown only on FireFox 18

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xss

I have a bit of code that works fine on Chrome, Safari, IE, and Opera. But for some reason on only FireFox 18 I get this problem

Error: Permission denied to access property 'document' 
 [Break On This Error]

window.opener.document.getElementById("creditsTotal").innerText = credits;

Here is the code in question (keep in mind only ff18 throws this XSS error)

```
chat_client.rtmp.update_chat_status = function(){
            //console.log("The overridden method has been called.");
            if (!this.chat.current_chat_user)
                return;

            this.log("Updating chat session.");
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url parthenon_chat.rtmp.views.update_chat_session %}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'session_id': this.chat.session_ids[this.chat.current_chat_user],
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': CSRF_TOKEN
                },
                success: function(credits) { 


                    //make sure that credits var is integer and non-negative
                    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
                    if(intRegex.test(credits)) {
                        console.log("Credits remaining: " + credits);
                       window.opener.document.getElementById("creditsTotal").innerText = credits;
                    }

                }
            });
```

Any thoughts? I haven't tried using an older version of ff18 to see if I'd get the same XSS exception.

Comment: and what does `url: "{% url parthenon_chat.rtmp.views.update_chat_session %}"` look like?

Comment: It is on the same domain as the parent window. Something like this: http://10.0.0.2/chat/conversation/?queue=8dcf98eb37182f64a87c6180c641b0b659f4e78cfa58472de55e37a2f63b7427&session_id=177&   There is no problem getting the data via AJAX...THE PROBLEM is updating the parent window from where this window was spawned with the ajax-gotten data

Comment: XSS is an attack vector, not a type of error.

Comment: Umm...not exactly...you may be attacked through XSS exploits, but browsers of late have been building in safe gaps to prevent XSS attacks, which means certain types methods are no longer allowed. Hence, my current problem. Just because you do a cross site script, that doesn't mean you have attacked or plan to attack your user. It only means you have accessed a script from a different domain, which hackers in the past used to great success. But that is NOT germane to my question: The above error is generated because an XSS exception has been lifted. Why does this only happen on FF18?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security exception seemed to be cause by a switching of ports by the chat app from the child to parent page, even though this was on the same domain. The solution to this was to use html5 spec 10.4, and re-write my javascript on both the child and parent windows accommodate. Here is the current WHATWG spec on getting around this XSS exception: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/web-messaging.html#web-messaging

Answer (score 1):

You know this won't work in internet explorer it only has partial on caniuse.com

See this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging

You have to have a fall back for ie